# Why can I no longer command Siri "go to sleep?"

Tags: big-sur, siri

I have been saying "hey Siri go to sleep" as I leave my home office every day since I got my iMac Retina a few weeks back.

Today I got these responses:
[image]

I haven't changed any settings, is it possible a recent update to Big Sur has changed something? It's the only use of Siri I really have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been monitoring this for some time now and it seems quite clear that Siri's performance degrades over time when my Mac is left running for days or weeks:

1. The time it takes the Siri popup to appear after saying "Hey Siri" slowly gets longer and longer. After a reboot it is instant, over time it can end up being several seconds
2. Some commands or wordings like "go to sleep" stop being recognised. I can still say "put this Mac to sleep" for example.

Rebooting fixes everything until it gradually gets annoying enough to reboot. Quite odd, presumably some subtle bug somewhere.